# Existing EF migrations became invisible after refactoring

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, refactoring, entity-framework-migrations

I use EF code first migrations in my project. At the moment I've got 2 migrations.
Tried to create database from scratch but `update-database` returns an error

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly
>   'Project.DAL'

On the other hand `enable-migrations` returns

> Migrations have already been enabled in project 'Project.DAL'

When I started Project I had configuration: `Project.Api`, `Project.Web` and `Project.Shared`(Migrations were here). Then I separated `Project.Shared` onto `Project.BLL`, `Project.Model` and `Project.DAL`(now Migrations here). Maybe that changes were the reason of current situation.

Comment: Is the correct project selected in package manager? Otherwise, parameterize your command: Enable-Migrations -ProjectName Project.DAL -StartUpProjectName Project.Web -Verbose

Comment: @SteveGreene Yes, I choose Project.DAL in package manager. I tried with parameters and unfortunately faced the same result

Comment: I would reset your migrations and see where that gets you (delete migration folder in VS, remove __MigrationHistory table in database, enable-migrations, add-migration Initial -IgnoreChanges, update-database –SourceMigration $InitialDatabase ).

Comment: @SteveGreene Ok will try in a moment. By the way would be safety to delete __MigrationHistory on production database ?

Comment: Given that a PROD database should always be backed up, then yes. __MigrationHistory is only used to make sure the prior migrations have been applied - so if all of them have then, yes, you can delete it. In fact we periodically remove migrations from all of our environments.

Comment: @SteveGreene I've already found a solution for my problem and have answered below. Anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of investigation I found and error by myself.
During refactoring I changed parameterless constructor of `Configuration` from

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "Project.DAL.ApplicationDbContext";
    }
```

To

```
    public Configuration(bool automaticMigrationsEnabled = false)
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = automaticMigrationsEnabled;
        ContextKey = "Project.DAL.ApplicationDbContext";
    }
```

I thought that conversion is equivalent but seems not. I placed old constructor near the new one and everything works fine.